# Issue with Trigger in Clob field

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 10g. Need to execute a trigger( BEFORE INSERT on each row) on a table.What the trigger does is that it sets a value to a varchar field.But the table has a CLOB field, so whenever the CLOB field contains value, trigger is not executed, otherwise it works properly and trigegr gets executed and it will set the value to the varchar field.What could be the reason?
Please help..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRIG_UPDATE_DISPLAY_NAME"
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON TABLE1
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   displayValue   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   SELECT cust_pk_prefix || cust_pk_next_value
     INTO displayValue
     FROM customer_pk
    WHERE     cust_pk_menu = :new.inc_menu_type
          AND cust_pk_cust_id = :new.inc_cust_id
          AND cust_pk_record_status = 'A';

   :new.inc_display_name := displayValue;

   UPDATE customer_pk
      SET cust_pk_next_value = cust_pk_next_value + 1
    WHERE     cust_pk_menu = :new.inc_menu_type
          AND cust_pk_cust_id = :new.inc_cust_id
          AND cust_pk_record_status = 'A';
END;
```

Comment: Can you provide the trigger code? Logically it should not matter if the clob field contains data or not.

Comment: Jon Tofte-Hansen  Sure.

create or replace 
TRIGGER "TRIG_UPDATE_DISPLAY_NAME" 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  displayValue varchar2(100);

BEGIN
    select cust_pk_prefix||cust_pk_next_value into displayValue from customer_pk where cust_pk_menu = :new.inc_menu_type and cust_pk_cust_id = :new.inc_cust_id and cust_pk_record_status = 'A';
    :new.inc_display_name := displayValue;
    update customer_pk set cust_pk_next_value = cust_pk_next_value+1 where cust_pk_menu = :new.inc_menu_type and cust_pk_cust_id = :new.inc_cust_id and cust_pk_record_status = 'A';
END;

Comment: If your where clause doesn't find a record in customer_pk it will write null to table1.inc_display_name. Can that be the case? Then the clob field status is a false lead.

Comment: No, even after removing the where clause, it is not working.Any other guess??

Comment: You should not remove the where clause because you will then update all columns. Find a case where it works, insert some data in the corresponding clob-field and try again. Does it fail now?

Comment: Hi @JonTofte-Hansen, had already tried that way.If clob value is null, then trigger will execute.Otherwise , won't.In both cases, the second statement ie  update customer_pk set cust_pk_next_value = cust_pk_next_value+1 where cust_pk_menu = :new.inc_menu_type and cust_pk_cust_id = :new.inc_cust_id and cust_pk_record_status = 'A'; will execute

Comment: Can you provide ddl for the involved tables (incl. constraints)? Are there other triggers?

Comment: Hi, Its too long.so providng only the clob part DDL...CREATE TABLE TABLE1
   ( "INC_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "INC_CUST_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "INC_EVTT_ID" NUMBER, 
 "INC_OBJ_ID" NUMBER,        }  LOB ("INC_DESCR") STORE AS (
  TABLESPACE "TEST_" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 PCTVERSION 10
  NOCACHE LOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)) ;

Comment: No, there are no other triggers used

Comment: That is not a working DDL. Please post it formatted in your question. If you provide the excact and working ddl/dml, I can try to reproduce the error. You have not provided version details.

Comment: Hi, I am using Oracle 10 g.Working DDL is as follows ..CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( "INC_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"INC_CUST_ID" NUMBER , "INC_EVTT_ID" NUMBER, "INC_OBJ_ID" NUMBER, "INC_DESCR" CLOB
)

Comment: What about customer_pk? Please put ddl for both tables, the trigger, and relevant insert statements. Edit your question and put the formated code there (indent by four spaces).If you do that properly, I can take the code to my own database and see if I can reproduce the behaviour you report, and maybe understand what is going on. Otherwise I can not help you, sorry.

Comment: CREATE TABLE TABLE1
   ( "INC_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "INC_CUST_ID" NUMBER, 
 "INC_EVTT_ID" NUMBER, 
 "INC_OBJ_ID" NUMBER, 
 "INC_DESCR" CLOB, 
 "INC_DISPLAY_NAME" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE)
   )
   
   create or replace 
TRIGGER "TRIG_UPDATE_DISPLAY_NAME1" 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  displayValue varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    :new.inc_display_name := 'hi';
END;                                                                                                               Actually, when i manually insert records to Table1, 'hi' gets set,but   we r inserting using hibernate

Comment: So when you use hibernate, the trigger is not run?

Comment: No,not run in the sense, no fields in Table1 gets set when INC_DESCR(clob) has value.Otherwise, no problem.

Comment: If you can make it work directly on the database it is a Hibernate problem. Maybe the trigger is disabled/enabled if the user you use through Hibernate has privileges for that. Try to connect with less privs to test that.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion.Forgot to mention that 2 nd statement given in trigger worked properly.    UPDATE customer_pk
      SET cust_pk_next_value = cust_pk_next_value + 1
    WHERE     cust_pk_menu = :new.inc_menu_type
          AND cust_pk_cust_id = :new.inc_cust_id
          AND cust_pk_record_status = 'A'.So assuming that it cant be a privilage problem